# Using php to connect to mysql using mod_dbd

Tags: php, mysql, dbd

I would like to use mod_dbd to implement connection pooling for my php application. I am able to define the mod_dbd module for apache and I can see the connections that it is opening, but I am not able to "hook on" those connections with my php code. I was trying mysql_connect with parameters and without as well as mysql_pconnect.

Welcome any advice,

Ariel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861876/php-and-mod-dbd

Answer (score 1):

In order to benefit from the connection pooling feature of mod_dbd you would need to run a threaded MPM so that several threads can share the connections in the pool. Unfortunately I do believe PHP is not thread-safe, and will not support threaded MPMs.

If you use mod_dbd with the pre-fork MPM (which is not threaded and recommended for PHP) mod_dbd will create a single persistent database connection, which does not give you any huge advantage compared to a database connection in PHP not using mod_dbd.

Answer (score 0):

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51865&edit=1

> One should implement this as an
>   extension like mysqlnd is implemented,
>   allowing others to inherit from the
>   abstraction code. Its quite possible
>   such a thing might come up in PECL,
>   but for the Core PHP its not very
>   likely that any of us are going to
>   work on it.
>
> Also you have to keep in mind that it
>   requires alot of changes to allow
>   connection pooling while under Apache,
>   and at the same time allowing an
>   extension to use another, non Apache
>   based webserver, like IIS to work
>   with. Else the extension would get way
>   too limited.

Just quoting from what I googled